# Send js varible to php file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to send my variable "var targetId" to my php file.
I try to make ajax request but nothing happens.

My js file :

```
$( ".project_item" ).click(function(e){

var targ = e.target;
var targetId = targ.dataset.id;
console.log(targetId);

$('.popUp').fadeIn("200");
$('header, main, footer').addClass('blur');

$.ajax({

    url: 'function.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {idVoulu: targetId},
    success: function(data){

    alert(data);
    console.log(data);
   }   
  });

});`
```

And my php file to get the data

```
$idProject = (isset($_POST['idVoulu'])) ? $_POST['idVoulu'] : 0;
if($idProject==0) { echo ' ID not found';}
```

Can you tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: What result are you getting? Is your PHP file getting called? Does the "success" function get called (do you get the alert)?

Comment: I dont get the alert, this my first step.
Function.php is the file where i want to send data

Comment: do a return or echo in your php
may be the idProject is not  equals to 0  thats why no return

Comment: idProject is well equals to 0. Maybe because there is no success

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't Find a problem on your code but you can try this may be this will help you

```
var mydata = "idVoulu='+targetId+'"; // make a string

    $.ajax({

        url: 'function.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: mydata,
        success: function(data){

        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
       }   
      });
```

Comment: Sorry i get the same result :/

Answer (score 0):

So, i made this and it works:

My js:

```
$( ".project_item" ).click(function(e) {
    var targ = e.target;
    var targetId = targ.dataset.id;

    $('.popUp').fadeIn("200");
    $('header, main, footer').addClass('blur');

    $.post('../function.php', { id: targetId }, function(response) {

     console.log("reponse : ", response)
    });
```

My php :

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $newID = $_POST['id'];  
    $response = 'Format a response here' . $newID;

    return print_r($response);
 }
```